# How to get json text into html DOM

Tags: javascript, json

I am able to get the data from an external URL JSON but cant put it into the DOM not too sure what I'm doing wrong but here's my code. I suspect that it has something to do with the obj.fruit.json but not too certain

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Starting Point</title>
    <script>
      function do_exercise()
      {
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET', 'http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/fruit.json', true);
            x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status ==200) {
            alert(x.responseText);
            obj = JSON.parse(text);
            document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML =
            obj.fruit.json[2].name + " " + 
            obj.fruit.json[2].description;
        }
      }
        x.send(null);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>           
      <button onclick="do_exercise();">Click Me</button>        
    </nav>
    <section id = "section1">
      <h1>Heading One</h1>
      <p>Paragraph One.</p>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

cheers

Comment: How your `response` looks like

Comment: probably duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529173/

Comment: where do you get obj.fruit? From the response of that URL I think you should be doing `obj[2].name` or `obj[2].description` to get correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Starting Point</title>
  <script>
    function do_exercise () {
        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET', 'http://tmaserv.scem.uws.edu.au/fruit.json', true);
        x.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status ==200) {
                obj = JSON.parse(x.responseText);
                document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML =
                obj[2].name + " " + 
                obj[2].description;
            }
        }

        x.send(null);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>           
      <button onclick="do_exercise();">Click Me</button>      
    </nav>
    <section id = "section1">
      <h1>Heading One</h1>
      <p>Paragraph One.</p>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks It worked, just didnt need the fruit,json  part cheers. btw if no too much trouble how do you list everything  e.g. instead of just [2] how do I get all of it? do I have to use a for loop? cheers

Comment: Yes a for loop would work, or you could rely on obj.map(function(fruit) { return fruit.name + fruit.description; }).join("<br />");