# attaching json into data attribute in an array of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm making a website with recipes in it and I am loading them from a json file via a Mustache.js template.
My json looks something like this:

```
{
"recipes":[
{"name": "A", preparationTime: "40min", "servings": "3", "image": "path/to/imageA"},
{"name": "B", preparationTime: "30min", "servings": "2", "image": "path/to/imageB"},
{"name": "C", preparationTime: "20min", "servings": "3", "image": "path/to/imageC"},
{"name": "D", preparationTime: "30min", "servings": "4", "image": "path/to/imageD"}
]
}
```

my template looks like this:

```
var recipeTemplate = "" +
"<div class='col-6 recipeUnit'>" +
"<div class='recipeItem row'>" + 
"<div class='recipeItem__image col-5'><img src='{{image}}' alt='recipe image'></div>" +
"<div class='recipeItem__description col-7'>" + 
"<h3 class='recipeTitle'>{{name}}</h3>" + 
"<div class='details'>" +
"<span>{{preparationTime}}</span>" +
"<span>{{servings}}</span>" +
"</div>" +
"<a class='buttonDetails' href='#'>see more</a>" +
"</div>" +
"</div>" +
"</div>";
```

And my ajax load function looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    loadRecipes()
    function loadRecipes(){

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "recipes.json", 
            dataType: "JSON",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
            $section.empty();
            for(var i = 0; i < data.recipes.length; i++){

                var recipe = data.recipes[i];
                var html = Mustache.to_html(recipeTemplate, recipe);
                $section.append(html);
                $button = $(".buttonDetails");
                $button.data.recipe = recipe;

            };

            $button.on("click", function(){

                console.log($(this).data.recipe)
                return false;


            }); 

        });

    }

})
```

I want to be able to store the json per specific recipe into the $button in each recipe displayed on the page. Everything works fine but when I want to console.log the data.recipe property when I click the button I always get the last array item from the json. I have been struggling with this for quite some time now and I don't understand why it's displaying the last item.
Originally I took the idea from telez here:
[Best practices for Storing JSON in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529173/best-practices-for-storing-json-in-dom).
I would appreciate if anyone could explain to me why is this problem happening and how could I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$button = $(".buttonDetails");` matches all the buttons appended to the document up to that point. So basically you iterate over all recipes and set the last receipts data to the all buttons for each recipe. This leaves you with all buttons data set to the last recipe.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

```
$button = $(".buttonDetails");
```

You get **all** the buttons and assign a recipe to all of them at once.
To avoid this, you should change your selector so it will search in the current template only.

Comment: Thank you Voskhod. Can you advise how do I get the current button? I have tried using $button = $(".buttonDetails").eq(i) but the result is still the same- I get the last item from json array console logged.

Comment: Try this selector:
    $button = $(html).find(".buttonDetails");

Comment: Still refers to the last item unfortunately :-(

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues here.

1. Your reference to `$button` is being reassign every iteration, so when you click the $button, it points to the last button that was bound.
2. Because your $button is being reassigned, the data associated with it will also be reassigned.

[Please see this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sidouglas/2um5vsLL/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $section = $('section');
    loadRecipes();
    function loadRecipes(){

            var solution = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < data.recipes.length; i++){
                var $button;
                var recipe = data.recipes[i];
                var html = Mustache.to_html(recipeTemplate, recipe);
                $section.append(html);
                $button = $(".recipeUnit:last .buttonDetails"); // get the last $button every time...
                $button.data.recipe = recipe;

                // capture each $button and store it in array. By doing so we ensure we don't reasign the button.
                                solution[i] = $button;   
                solution[i].data('recipe',recipe);
           };

         // $button here is going to be the D button, because $button is assigned 4 times.
          $button.on("click",function(){
               console.log('This is wrong, because the $button variable is repointed on every iteration',$(this).data.recipe);
                 return false;
           });  

          // here we have really do have 4 different buttons...
          solution.map(function($button){
            $button.on('click',function(e){
                            console.log($(this).data().recipe);
            });
          });
     }

})
```

Comment: Simon thank you so much for your help and the fiddle. This solution really works :-). I was thinking that the $button should be saved into an array every time... But didn't think that you could create an event handler in a map function. I will need to read a bit more on that. I am just only wondering about the use of  $button = $(".recipeUnit:last .buttonDetails"). Why this and not  $button = $(".buttonDetails").eq(i). It seems to work.

Comment: `$(".buttonDetails").eq(i)` that's fine too. Hope you got it sorted.